# Is there a way to specify port range in nginx config upstream block?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm looking for a way to specify a port range in the nginx upstream block.

Is there a way to turn this:

```
upstream backend {

    least_conn;

    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    server 127.0.0.1:3001;
    server 127.0.0.1:3002;
    server 127.0.0.1:3003;
    server 127.0.0.1:3004;
    server 127.0.0.1:3005;
}
```

into something like this?:

```
upstream backend {

    least_conn;

    server 127.0.0.1:[3000:3005]
}
```

Comment: No. You could use plenty of other tools to generate nginx config.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach to operate host with [Openresty](https://openresty.org/en/) which is based on Nginx and is capable of running Lua plugins. The snippet of code to make it work would look like this

```
upstream backend {
        balancer_by_lua_block {
        local balancer = require "ngx.balancer"
        local start_port=3000
        local max_port=start_port+5
        repeat
            local ok, err = balancer.set_current_peer('127.0.0.1', start_port)
            if not ok then
                ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "failed to set the current peer: ", err)
                return ngx.exit(500)
        end
        start_port=start_port+1
        until start_port>max_port
    }
```